# Using Pygame Module from imported script

Tags: python, namespaces, import, pygame

Greetings!
I'm creating a simple snake game. I want to expand my classes in different modules e.i. have menu class in a separate script from my main game loop. In other words, I want my imported script to take the pygame init which was called earlier in main script.

Here is a quick example using pseudo code of my problem:

one.py

```
def version():
    print pygame.version
```

In main.py i have imported pygame and did pygame.init(). From here, I also want to use the def version() from one.py

main.py

```
import pygame
import one

pygame.init()

one.version()
```

However, it gives me the no pygame defined error. I know the reason why it give me an error is because when the one.py is called from within the main.py, it doesnt retain the declarations from main.py.

What I want to know is a method to doing the mentioned above that will actually work.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The imports of the module that imports module X don't leak through to X's namespace (which is a good thing - it would either require dynamic scoping or C/C++-style `#include`, both are almost never useful and often even harmful). It's a completely seperate namespace on its own. If you want to use something (e.g. `pygame`) in a module (e.g. `one`), import it there.

Comment: I have thought of that; but is it efficient? If I do go that route, I'll have to import Pygame in each module as necessary. Perhaps if I created a separate module which has a function that imports Pygame when called?

Comment: @user577317: Yes it's efficient. Creating a separate module is pointless, because you would have to import that instead.

Comment: @user577317: You can't manipulate the caller's namespace (well, perhaps you can, but it would be an unreliable hack, take a significant amount of work and is a bad idea to begin with). **Just import them**, for god's sake. This question is yet another example of why optimization without understanding is pointless and harmful ;) Importing a module that was already imported (in the currently running interpreter process - you generally only have one for one program, of course) just gives you a reference to the already imported module. I.e. no inefficiency.

Answer (score 1):

Python's import model is the following: If you need module `a.b.c` in your module `d.e.f`, then add an `import a.b.c` (or similar) to the beginning of `d/e/f.py`. (This is similar to how Java's import works.) So if you have many modules (e.g. `d.e.f1`, `d.e.f2`, ...) which need many modules (e.g. `a.b.c1`, `a.b.c2`, ...), then you should import each required module from each of your modules, resulting multiple copies of the same `import` statement in your module source files. It looks like that a more compact import model (where you have to import the same module only once) would be better, but that has a very important disadvantage: the compact import model would use a global namespace, and it would make dependency tracking (e.g. who needs this code?, where does this code come from?) much harder. So every time you write an import line which you think is not necessary, remember that this is the (small) price you're paying for maintainable code.

Comment: Hmm...interesting. Thanks for the advice, I'll keep it in mind.